# Ruby on rails actiontext content does not display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trix, actiontext

I'm currently learning Ruby on Rails, and for my first project, I'm creating a blog application by following the instructions in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yj3toc3h0WE&list=PLm8ctt9NhMNWD939gE728i13W999EFS0n&index=17). However, I've encountered an issue when trying to improve the edit textbox using Action Text. I followed the instructions from the linked video, but my text box appears like this:

[image]

Do you have any idea what might be wrong? I'm unsure about what additional information you need to better understand the problem, so please let me know, and I'll provide you with the necessary code. For now, here's how **my application.html.erb** file looks:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>RD</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "trix" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "actiontext", "data-turbo-track":"reload" %>

  </head>
  <body>

  <%= render 'home/header' %>
  <div class="container"> 
    <br/>
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

    <div>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= button_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you including the `trix` JavaScript somewhere in your app?

Comment: I added "    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbo-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'trix' %>" to application.html.erb file, but it did not change anything. I do not know if this is what you mean, if not please explain it further.

Comment: Is that loading Trix though?  If you go to the JavaScript console in the browser and type `Trix.VERSION` does it say anything?

Comment: This message appears: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Trix is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1", so I assume that I should include trix JavaScript somewhere else in the code, but where?

Comment: How did you install Trix?  Did you use something like [the `action_text:install` task here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html#installation)?  Or `yarn add trix`?  If you just want to test this without learning more about how assets are managed in Rails, I would suggest following [this info](https://github.com/basecamp/trix#getting-started) to load Trix directly from a CDN.